# How to end the pattern matching in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I need to implement a function takes an element `elt` and a list `lst` , and returns the position of the ﬁrst occurrence of `elt` in `lst`.

This is my answer:

```
elementPosition :: Eq t => t ->[t] -> Int
elementPosition t [] = 0 
elmentPosition t lst 
    | t == head lst  = 1
    | otherwise      = (elementPosition t (tail lst))+1
```

However, if `elt` is not in `lst`, I need to return 0. but this code will return the length of `lst`. Can I do something to return `0` when the first pattern is matched? If not, How can I implement this function?

Comment: I'd argue the right solution here is not using `0` to indicate the element is missing (which causes your `Int` result to have two possible meanings). That is why the `elemIndex` function bipll mentions [in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49278937/2751851) returns a `Maybe Int` rather than an `Int`.

Comment: As a general suggestion, if you are using `head` and `tail`, you are probably doing it in a non idiomatic way. These are dangerous partial functions which should be avoided when possible. Here, pattern matching on `(x:xs)` would simplify the code, and remove the partial functions.

Answer (score 3):

You have to turn your recursion into tail one, so that the final decision is made at the top of the stack, not on its bottom. This way you'll need to pass the distance currently accumulated from the head of the list as an argument (you'll need this distance when a match is found but can discard it if there's none). Something like

```
elementPosition :: Eq t => t ->[t] -> Int
elementPosition pat lst = elementPosition' 1 pat lst where
    elementPosition' _ _ [] = 0
    elementPosition' i pat (h:t) | pat == h = i
                                 | otherwise = elementPosition' (i + 1) pat t
```

But note that standard library has it already covered:

```
import Data.List

elementPosition :: Eq t => t ->[t] -> Int
elementPosition p l = maybe 0 succ $elemIndex p l
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
elementPosition :: Eq t => Int -> t -> [t] -> Int
elementPosition _ _ [] = 0
elementPosition pos key (x:xs)
    | key == x   = pos
    | otherwise  = elementPosition (pos + 1) key xs
```

and then `elementPosition 0` will do what you want

Comment: I recommend forcing `pos` before recursing, otherwise you get nasty thunk buildup. ``otherwise = pos `seq` elementPosition (pos + 1) key xs``

Answer (score 2):

The other answers discuss how to achieve this by adding an accumulator. However I think it can also be enlightening to see how to do it without an accumulator; the trick is just to check if the return value from the recursive call is `0` and maintain that value instead of incrementing if it is. So:

```
elementPosition :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Int
elementPosition t [] = 0
elementPosition t lst
    | t == head lst = 1
    | otherwise = case elementPosition t (tail lst) of
        0 -> 0
        n -> n+1
```

Comment: I see: here, `0` would represent `Nothing`, and `n+1` would represent `Just n`. This exploit the standard bijection `Maybe Nat -> Nat`. Using `Maybe`s would still be more understandable, though :)

Comment: @Albert, what the heck are you saying? You're going to use his code and try not to get caught? Aside from academic honesty problems, that's a pretty good way to piss people off on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: @Albert Excuse me, what? No: if you are not allowed to plagiarize, then the solution is not to plagiarize; a solution in which you plagiarize and attempt to hide it is not acceptable, neither to me, to your instructor, to the rules of this site, nor to your good education. If you learned something from this answer, I am pleased; but it is your responsibility to ask your questions ethically and use the answers ethically.

Comment: @DanielWagner I apologyze for my unreasonable request. I did not realize the importance of sharing and just thought to finish my work. I know this place is perfect for sharing our thinking and communicating. Although I am a newbie here, I should know this. 
Sorry again and your answer did help me a lot, I will use it in a right way. I hope I can learn more from you.

Answer (score 1):

Also, using `zip` (to make the list a list of tuples of elements and their indexes) and `filter` (to filter out the value we are looking for) we can get this definition:

```
elementPosition :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Int
elementPosition e xs =
  case filter ((== e) . fst) xsIndexed of
    [] -> 0
    (_, i):_ -> i
  where xsIndexed = zip xs [1..]
```

As suggested by @dfeuer, we can get this in a one-liner:

```
import Data.Maybe

elementPosition :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Int
elementPosition e = maybe 0 fst . listToMaybe . filter ((== e) . snd) . zip [1..]
```

Comment: If you're going for that style, you can mix the rest of the pattern matching using `maybe` with `listToMaybe`.